# Throttle - call a function at most every N milliseconds?

Tags: c#, f#

The function `callWebServiceAsync` in the following function will get rejected if it's called too frequently. It may take several milliseconds to one minute to finish.

**F#**

```
let doWorkAsync p = async { // doWorkAsync will be called many times
    ....
    let! ret = callWebServiceAsync p' // need to be throttled, high volumn of requestion in a short time will cause blocking
    ....
    let ret' = process ret
    ret'
}
```

**C#**

```
async Task<T> DoWorkAsync(S p) // DoWorkAsync will be called many times
{
    ....
    ret = await CallWebServiceAsync(...); // need to be throttled, high volumn of requestion in a short time will cause blocking
    ....
    return Process(ret);
}
```

How to throttle the call frequency? I'm not sure how they detect the calls so it's better to call the function evenly (no burst requests).

Comment: It sounds like you need a FIFO stack between two threads -- one thread loads the requests onto the stack; one thread calls callAnotherServiceAsync at a limited rate. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Does callAnotherServiceAsync return anything or can you fire-and-forget? You have let!, but no label. Perhaps you mean do! ?

Comment: Yes, the function returns value which will be consumed by the caller. I've corrected the question.

Comment: There's quartz.net, but I have no experience with it for sub-second precision, so don't know whether it's suitable for that.

Comment: What do you want to do if an existing method call is already in-flight, and the method is attempted called again?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen it should be allowed as long as the frequency of the calls are under the threshold.

Comment: And what **exactly** should happen if it is above the threshold?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, the remote service provider will *block* the caller's IP from accessing their services.

Comment: No, I mean what should happen with the method call? If you don't want to actually call the service, what should it return for T?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first reaction would be to use a [`MailboxProcessor`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/MailboxProcessor).  That's how you generally force all calls to go through a single gateway.

Below is a `throttle` function that will return an async continuation at most once per timespan.  High level, it

1. grabs an invocation requests from the message queue (`inbox.Receive`). This request contains a channel to return the results.
2. checks if there's any need to delay from the previous run, and sleeps
3. notes the start time of the current invocation (note you could swap this and step 4 if you want to throttle based on the end time of the invocations)
4. triggers the caller (`chan.Reply`)
5. loops to grab another request

The code is as follows

```
let createThrottler (delay: TimeSpan) =
  MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
    let rec loop (lastCallTime: DateTime option) =
      async {
        let! (chan: AsyncReplyChannel<_>) = inbox.Receive()
        let sleepTime =
          match lastCallTime with
          | None -> 0
          | Some time -> int((time - DateTime.Now + delay).TotalMilliseconds)
        if sleepTime > 0 then
          do! Async.Sleep sleepTime
        let lastCallTime = DateTime.Now
        chan.Reply()
        return! loop(Some lastCallTime)
      }
    loop None)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  // Dummy implementation of callWebServiceAsync
  let sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
  let callWebServiceAsync i =
    async {
      printfn "Start %d %d" i sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
      do! Async.Sleep(100)
      printfn "End %d %d" i sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
      return i
    }

  // Create a throttler MailboxProcessor and then the throttled function from that.
  let webServiceThrottler = createThrottler (TimeSpan.FromSeconds 1.)
  let callWebServiceAsyncThrottled i =
    async {
       do! webServiceThrottler.PostAndAsyncReply(id)
       return! callWebServiceAsync i
    }

  // Some tests
  Async.Start(async { let! i = callWebServiceAsyncThrottled 0
                      printfn "0 returned %d" i
                      let! i = callWebServiceAsyncThrottled 1
                      printfn "1 returned %d" i
                      let! i = callWebServiceAsyncThrottled 2
                      printfn "2 returned %d" i })
  Async.Start(callWebServiceAsyncThrottled 3 |> Async.Ignore)
  Async.Start(callWebServiceAsyncThrottled 4 |> Async.Ignore)
  Async.Start(callWebServiceAsyncThrottled 5 |> Async.Ignore)
  Async.Start(callWebServiceAsyncThrottled 6 |> Async.Ignore)
  Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
  0
```

If you run this, you'll see that it throttles your calls to that service as desired, no matter whether you're running in parallel or in series or both.

Comment: Nice! It seems there is not an easy way to do this in c#

Comment: @ca9163d9 It can be ported, but probably would look bad.  Easier to create this as a library function in F# and add a C# friendly wrapper on top of it.  BTW I updated the code to allow for the case where e.g. you want to throttle to 100ms and each call takes 1s.  So the above will allow multiple calls to `callWebServiceAsync` in parallel, but won't invoke them more frequently than 100ms.  The previous code prevents parallel calls to web service entirely, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit the call frequency to something in the millisecond range, you'll have to use a Win32 call to get the timestamp with a higher resolution than is generally available using `System.DateTime`.  I'd probably use `QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime` to get the time in 100ns increments.  Then, you could just keep track of the last time you made a call and asynchronously sleep until the interval had elapsed, using a lock to synchronize updates to the last call time:

```
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open System.Runtime.Versioning
open System.Threading

// Wrap the Win32 call to get the current time with 1-millisecond resolution
module private Timestamp =

    [<DllImport("kernel32.dll")>]
    [<ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)>]
    extern bool QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime (int64& value)

    let inline private queryUnbiasedInterruptTime () =
        let mutable ticks = 0L
        if QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime &ticks
        then Some ticks
        else None

    /// Get the current timestamp in milliseconds
    let get () =
        match queryUnbiasedInterruptTime() with
        | Some ticks -> ticks / 1000L
        | _ -> DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond


// Stub for request and response types
type Request = Request
type Response = Response

// Minimum time between calls (ms) =
let callFrequencyThreshold = 10L

// A wrapper around the call to the service that will throttle the requests
let doWorkAsync : Request -> Async<Response> =
    // Milliseconds since last call to service
    let mutable lastCallTime = 0L

    // Lock to protect the last call time
    let syncRoot = obj()

    // The real call to the service
    let callService request =
        async {
            // Simulate work
            do! Async.Sleep 1000 
            return Response
        }

    // Accept each request and wait until the threshold has elapsed to call the service
    fun request ->
        async {
            let rec run () =
                lock syncRoot <| fun () ->       
                    async {
                        let currentTime = Timestamp.get()
                        if currentTime - lastCallTime > callFrequencyThreshold
                        then lastCallTime <- currentTime
                             return! callService request
                        else do! Async.Sleep <| int (callFrequencyThreshold - (currentTime - lastCallTime))
                             return! run ()
                    }
            return! run ()
        }
```

However, I would not recommend a time-based approach to throttling unless absolutely necessary.  Personally, I would favor something like a semaphore to limit the number of concurrent calls to the service.  This way, you can ensure only 1 call to the service at a time if that's what's required, or allow a tunable `n` calls to the service at a time based on the environment, etc.  It also simplifies the code significantly, and in my opinion, gives a more reliable implementation:

```
open System.Threading

// Stub for request and response types
type Request = Request
type Response = Response

// A wrapper around the call to the service that will throttle the requests
let doWorkAsync : Request -> Async<Response> = 
    // A semaphore to limit the number of concurrent calls
    let concurrencyLimit = 10
    let semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(concurrencyLimit, concurrencyLimit)

    // The real call to the service
    let callService request =
        async {
            // Simulate work
            do! Async.Sleep 1000 
            return Response
        }

    // Accept each request, wait for a semaphore token to be available, 
    // then call the service
    fun request ->
        async {
            do! semaphore.WaitAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
            return! callService request
        }
```

Comment: For the second solution, will the code generate a lot of requests if there are a lot of `callService` calls which can be done in really short time? This may cause the remote service to block the caller.

Comment: In the second solution, only `n` requests to the service will be sent at any one time, where `n` is the `concurrencyLimit` used to create the semaphore.  If each call takes 100ms and you allow 5 concurrent calls, then you will have a maximum of 50 calls per second.

Comment: What values need to be set if no more than one call in a second?

Comment: It doesn't work that way.  You could set the `concurrencyLimit` to 1, that would mean "one call at a time".  However, if that call only takes 100ms, then it would still allow 10 requests per second, it's just that those requests would never be hitting the service at the same time.  If you must enforce a time-based limit, then you'll need something like the first solution.